# Azure App Insights issue with end to end tracing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I seem to be having some issues with tracing end to end using Azure functions and Service Bus Queue.

I have essentially a HTTP Trigger, that will then put the JSON message body onto the Service Bus Queue as a Message - with a generated Correlation Id (guid).

I have the Service Bus as a queue - this is fine.

I then have a Service Bus Queue Trigger function that pulls off the message from the queue. This is working fine.

However, the Service Map and the telematary and the request does not provide the end to end trace. It is split into two, my HTTP Trigger and Service Bus Trigger.
The operation-ids are different.

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the HTTP Trigger SEND function

```
        [FunctionName("SendQueueMessage")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        [ServiceBus("busqueue", Connection = "xxxxx", EntityType = EntityType.Queue)] ICollector<Message> outputQueueItem)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Processing a request.");
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        outputQueueItem.Add(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody)) 
                            { 
                                CorrelationId = correlationId
                            });
        return new OkObjectResult($"Successful CorrelationId: {correlationId}");
    }
```

Here is the Queue Trigger:

```
[FunctionName("RetrieveFromBusQueue")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("busqueue", 
                                                Connection = "xxxxxxxx")]Message messageItem, 
                            ILogger log)
    {

        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageItem.Body)}");
        log.LogInformation($"Message ID: {messageItem?.CorrelationId}");
    }
```

Is there some setting?
Both these functions are under the same FunctionApp.
It strangely never factors into the MAP the queue either.. I'm so confused here.

I am invoking the HTTP Trigger through the  CODE and TEST page in Azure against the trigger function. Is it something to do with HTTP headers?

Can someone point me in the correct direction to go with this please?

**UPDATE:**

So... turns out, if I use a much older version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights nuget package...  2.10.0 instead of 2.16.0 it actually traces my call to the Service bus and off the queue - with the correct display in the MAP.

This is absolutely bizarre to say the least - pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure out what I had done wrong. I still am unsure of why the latest version is causing this issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing) help?

Comment: are you using the latest versions of all the SDKs involved? Especially >3.0.0 for the Service Bus SDK

Comment: @PeterBons unfortunately I have read through this and had no such luck I am afraid.

Comment: @silent  - yes all up to date.   I cannot understand why when creating functions via Visual Studio and publishing them to Azure, they dont have the same tracing as you find when creating the same functions in Azure directly..

Comment: @KyleK, it's might be a bug, could you please raise this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues)? And please add your workaround as an answer, it can help others who have the same issue:).

Comment: I've reaised an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2153

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug in the new version 2.16.0.

As per the comment, you'd better raise an issue about this in it's github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues).

Comment: I've raised an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2153

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently with 3.1.6

Upgrading to 3.1.13 (latest) didn't help.

There is a compatibility problem in version >= 3.1.4, downgrading to 3.1.3 fixed the problem for me.